# using toPromise() and observable doesn't work async

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, promise, observable

I'm a begineer using angular and firebase, and I'm stuck at some point of my learning. I'm not native english.

I followed a tutorial using realtime db, but I'm now trying to exercise myself using firestore.

I got a collection called "categories", which contains categories like "toys", "pizza" or whatever.

My goal is to retrieve this categories using a similar approach of the tutorial I saw earlier, so please don't send me on something completely different, i'm trying to learn, not to make this work (well, in some way but.. you understand ahah).

So this is my service

```
getCategories () {
    let categories = [];
    this.db.collection("categories").get().toPromise().then(function(querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            categories[doc.id] = doc.data();
          });
      console.log("getCategories() returned : ");
      console.log(categories);
      return categories;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });
  }
```

and this is my component

```
export class ProductFormComponent {

  categories$;

  constructor(categoryService: CategoryService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to using "toPromise()" in order to create a promise that will get all the categories, and display it in a observable called categories$.

Unfortunately it seems that the data is getting in the console few instants after the page is render (because it's async), but the observable doesn't catch the change, it stays undefined forever.

I'm using the async "tag" but it doesn't solve anything.

I have done a lot of research but I can't understand what's going on, so I hope somebody will be able to help me here.

If I find my answer (no matter how stupid) I will post it here anyway, so my post will not be useless.

Thank you everyone, I hope you are not too annoyed to receive begineer question.

Comment: My guess is that your observable is not finite, and since it's not finite you are not getting any result.
Either way, it will be better to stick with `Observables` and operators such as `take(1)` instead of using promises.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getCategories()` method does not return anything, so `this.categories$` will be `undefined` forever.

If you are converting it to a promise, just to want it returned as an Observable again, I don't think you should convert it in the first place.

Updated service that returns an observable

```js
// you may want to type your observable better...
getCategories (): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.db.collection("categories").get().pipe(
        map(querySnapshot => {
          let categories = []; //I don't think you actually want an array here, but thats what your existing code had
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // you were originally  trying to set the index of an array to be the doc ID, this is probably going to cause an issue
            // categories[doc.id] = doc.data();
            // this will add the data to the array, you probably lose the ID though
            categories.push(doc.data());
          });
          console.log("getCategories() returned : ");
          console.log(categories);
          return categories;
         
        }),
        catchError(error => { 
           console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
           return []; // You need to determine what to do here, return an empty array, or possibly re-throw the error with throwError(error)
        });

    );
```

Updated component.  Note that we're still not subscribing so it still won't do anything.  You should subscribe in the template somewhere via `async` pipe.

```js
export class ProductFormComponent {

  categories$: Observable<any[]>; // type this better...

  constructor(categoryService: CategoryService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
  }
}
```

Example template with async pipe

```html
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let category of categories$ | async">
{{category | json}} <!-- do something better here to show your data -->
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand what my error was when you are talking about "doesn't return anything'. Thanks !

Is "Observable<any[]>" something that is recommended for safety and better understanding or it is something that I can't avoid ?

I made the changes, I doesn't work, It still retrieve data from the firestore, but I can't make them appear on the page, even with the exampl template.

It seems that the getCategories() is called twice. I have the console message "getCategories() returned... array" two times. Maybe I made a mistake doing the changes.. 

Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing the full working code, I can't tell why its getting called twice.  If you are using the aysnc pipe that will subscribe in the template, but you may also be calling .subscribe() somewhere in your component as well.  Its good to type the return of your methods so the compiler will complain if you have a bug in your code and you're not actually returning what you though.